# javascript, цепочка промисов для setTimeout

Tags: javascript, promise, settimeout

Изучаю промисы. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как выполнить такую задачу:
Вывод даты через секунду после начала выполнения, потом через 2, потом через 6, и т.д.
После первого вывода даты перевожу промис в статус `fullfilled` , далее правильно дата выводиться через 2 сек, но потом следующая дата выводиться через 4 сек (а должна через 6 сек.), т.е следующий промис не дожидается выполнения предыдущего (в смысле выполнения `logDate` метода). Как заставить его ждать ?
Делаю так:

```js
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    logDate();
    resolve();
  }, 1000);
});

promise
  .then(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      logDate();
    }, 2000);

  })
  .then(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      logDate();
    }, 6000);
  });

function logDate() {
  console.log(new Date());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы попасть во второй then после выполнения таймаута надо в первом возвращать промис, и резолвить его по окончанию таймера:

```js
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    logDate();
    resolve();
  }, 1000);
});

promise
  .then(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        logDate();
        resolve();
      }, 2000);
    });
  })
  .then(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      logDate();
    }, 6000);
  });

function logDate() {
  console.log(new Date());
}
```

Еще пример сокращения и читабельности вашего кода:

```js
logDate()
  .then(() => logDate(2000))
  .then(() => logDate(6000));

function logDate(delay = 1000) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(new Date());
      resolve();
    }, delay);
  });
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное !